# Is there an online resource listing magic shows in Central Europe?

Tags: europe, online-resources

In Las Vegas there is the [Penn and Teller theater](https://www.vegas.com/shows/magic/penn-and-teller-las-vegas/index_v1.html) with regularly scheduled shows by professional magicians. Is there an online resources listing such shows within Europe?

It doesn't have to be a specific type of magic, as long as it's suitable for adults and not just kids. Most Google searches return listings of individual magicians or shows, rather than a list of options in different regions.

There is a list of [circus shows](http://www.europeancircus.eu/?page_id=995) in Central Europe, but those usually contain a lot more elements than just 'magic'.

Comment: Are theaters were one person/group performs a few times a week fine or are you looking for a place is used by a variety of magicians?

Comment: Europe is extremely broad, covering dozens of countries. A quick google shows one in Spain, easily found.  Can you please narrow this down, as currently it's matching the 'too broad' definition perfectly.

Comment: Especially if the answer to my question is "the former" than there are at least half a dozen such places in Germany alone.

Comment: We're already getting a London answer, and that's just one city among many. I'm putting on hold until the scope can be narrowed.

Comment: @MarkMayo limited the scope to Central Europe. I've tried looking in Czech Republic and Slovakia and couldn't find any, so the answers would probably be limited to Germany/Austria.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search found me an ['what is on' magic site.](http://www.magicweek.co.uk/thisweek_whatson.htm)
And in the list there I recognized a show in London, which was recently mentioned on BBC TV.
Here is a [link to a booking site](https://tickets.delfontmackintosh.co.uk/index.asp?ShoID=1740&profile=IN5&Promo=N13) where you can book tickets for that show.

An other way in might be finding a magician you would like to see and go to his/her website and see where they perform.
[Like the site of Hans Klok.](http://www.hansklok.net/)

Added after your edit to 'Central Europe':
Central Europe is quite a difficult search term for Google in my view, you might be better off searching for separate countries in the region.
I found [one Vienna group](http://www.magischerklub.org/en/scedule.php).

I guess you get better results looking in the local languages.
Zaubershow seems to work.
As I do not speak German, I am a bit limited in searching.

Comment: I've edited the question to be less broad.